# Autowired field is null in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I am implementing a simple spring boot app:

`Content` class:

```
Entity
@Table(name = "content")
public class Content implements Serializable {

public Content() {
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private long id;

@NotNull
private String title;

//getter/setter and toString()
}
```

`ContentRepository` interface:

```
@Repository
public interface ContentRepository extends CrudRepository<Content, Long>{
}
```

`RepositoryConfiguration`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories({"com.tarameshgroup.derakht.repository"})
@EntityScan("com.tarameshgroup.derakht.domain")
@ComponentScan("com.tarameshgroup.derakht")
public class RepositoryConfiguration {
}
```

`Application` class for testing:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import({RepositoryConfiguration.class})
public class Application {

    private static final Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Autowired
    static ContentRepository contentRepository; // Why is null?

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Running application...");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);

        System.out.println("contentRepository: " + contentRepository); //why contentRepository is null?
    }
```

Comment: Where is the class that implements interface ContentRepository. AS when you autowire object of implemented class is created. As I can't see any class implementing it. THat's why the error

Comment: @Naruto There is no need for implementing class in `spring boot ` applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define ContentRepository as static field. either make it non static or use this trick [@autowired in static classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392692/autowired-in-static-classes)